# Returning comma separated values in SQL Server in one element

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below query which I am using to return comma separated result.

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + em.EMAIL 
        FROM(
            SELECT  DISTINCT USR.EMAIL AS EMAIL
          FROM PRNCPLS A, PRNCPLS B, USER_INFO USR,
          RELATIONSHIPS C
          WHERE A.ID = C.PARENTID 
          AND B.ID = C.CHILDID
          AND A.TYPE = 'USER' and B.TYPE = 'ROLE'
          AND A.ID = USR.ID
          and B.NAME = 'Approver'
          AND USR.EMAIL IS NOT NULL) em
        ORDER BY em.EMAIL FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, ''
) AS Output
```

I have a requirement to update this query in a way that the first line of the SQL statement (and not the output) always start like this

`SELECT EMAIL FROM`

This is required since the tool I am using for some reason expects `FROM` in the first line and just one single element in the `SELECT` clause. My query actually only returns one element, so I was hoping to somehow update it.

Expected output - abcd@gmail.com,1234@yahoo.com,xyz@gmail.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, bear in mind that this is an obsolete way of writing joinings: < FROM PRNCPLS A, PRNCPLS B, USER_INFO USR,
          RELATIONSHIPS C >, you should start for converting into INNER JOIN way

Comment: **[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)**

Comment: so at the moment you get a single field containing comma separated values, but you wish to append 'SELECT EMAIL FROM ' in front of it, is that correct?  Or do you also want to split up the comma separated list in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM (

SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + em.EMAIL 
        FROM(
            SELECT  DISTINCT USR.EMAIL AS EMAIL
          FROM PRNCPLS A, PRNCPLS B, USER_INFO USR,
          RELATIONSHIPS C
          WHERE A.ID = C.PARENTID 
          AND B.ID = C.CHILDID
          AND A.TYPE = 'USER' and B.TYPE = 'ROLE'
          AND A.ID = USR.ID
          and B.NAME = 'Approver'
          AND USR.EMAIL IS NOT NULL) em
        ORDER BY em.EMAIL FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, '') AS EMAIL
) AS Output
```

Beware of both "...EMAIL...":

- "SELECT EMAIL ..."
- "...1,1,'') AS EMAIL...".

Comment: Thank you very much Grimm, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi @Newbie, I'm glad that you found a solution. Just to mention this: This is exactly the same as my answer. It is a `SELECT` where the existing query is wrapped as sub-query...

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
SELECT 'SELECT EMAIL FROM ' + STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + em.EMAIL 
        FROM(
            SELECT  DISTINCT USR.EMAIL AS EMAIL
          FROM PRNCPLS A, PRNCPLS B, USER_INFO USR,
          RELATIONSHIPS C
          WHERE A.ID = C.PARENTID 
          AND B.ID = C.CHILDID
          AND A.TYPE = 'USER' and B.TYPE = 'ROLE'
          AND A.ID = USR.ID
          and B.NAME = 'Approver'
          AND USR.EMAIL IS NOT NULL) em
        ORDER BY em.EMAIL FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, ''
) AS Output;
```

or is there more to how the data is formatted?

Comment: I think, the OP is not looking for `SELECT EMAIL FROM <list of emails>`, but rather for a certain format to articulate the query...

Comment: @Cato Thanks for your answer, but in also includes the text SELECT EMAIL FROM  in the output unfortunately.

Comment: Expected output - abcd@gmail.com,1234@yahoo.com,xyz@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing

```
SELECT 'SELECT EMAIL FROM '
UNION
... Your existing query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap almost any `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT t.SomeColumn FROM
(
     place your existing SELECT here
) t;
```

This would not work with a CTE-query, but CTEs can be shifted into sub-queries themselves.

**Hint**: Try to avoid *old-fashioned JOINs* if possible. There is a good link provided by Sami in the comments...

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thanks for the answer. I have updated my query to use JOINs. I modified the query as you mentioned, but it doesnt work. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: @Newbie what does *but it doesn't work* mean? Please provide more details

Comment: unfortunately, changing the joins to the modern method, will not actually alter the output.  Furthermore, it is possible that there will be no performance gain.